# Dynamic fixed effect model

Tags: lm, panel-data, plm, economics

I am trying to test the hypothesis of economic convergence in European countries. I have found that a consistent estimator is Bias corrected LSDV (see, Kiviet (1995)). I've seen that there is a relative command in Stata, however I haven't found something relevant in R. Does anyone know how I can implement the estimator in R?

I have performed the fixed effects model but we know that this estimator when it comes to estimating a dynamic model is inconsistent. Ι want to apply bias corrected LSDV estimator for a more efficient and consistent research.

```
model_fe <- plm(pdata$log_gdp_t ~ pdata$log_gdp_(t-1), data = pdata, model = "within", effect = "individual")
```